# Vue Js open sketchpad in vue-js-modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am new with `Vue` and trying to open sketchpad inside `vue-js-modal`.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here.

I am using [VueModal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-js-modal) and [vue-signature-pad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-signature-pad).

It works fine on the page but I could not make it run in the modal.

Here is the link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5jlq1yk8l)

`App.vue` code is as follow

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-dialog />
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-2">
          <div class="col-6 mt-2">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" @click="showButtonsDialog">
              Open Dialog
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
       <div class="col-12 mt-2">
          <VueSignaturePad
            id="signature"
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            ref="signaturePad"
          />
        </div>            
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
    name: "App",
    methods: {
       showButtonsDialog() {
           this.$modal.show("dialog", {
           title: "Some Title",
           text:'<VueSignaturePad id="signature" width="100%" height="200px" ref="signaturePad"/>',
           buttons: [
           {
               title: "CANCEL",
               handler: () => {
                   this.$modal.hide("dialog");
               }
           }]
          });
        }
      }
    };    
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think `text` only work with plain text, not Vue component. To include Vue component in your modal, you can declare it in template

```
  <modal name="example"
   width="80%"
   height="80%">
      <VueSignaturePad
        id="signature"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        ref="signaturePad"
      />
  </modal>
```

and when you want to show it

```
showButtonsDialog() {
  this.$modal.show("example")
}
```

Demo on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zrorrw07jm)

Comment: I guess the documentation is misleading